# Soap 1.1 and Soap 1.2 related

Tags: soap

I'm using some examples from netbeans tutorials to develop some soap services. 
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html
Now my question is 
1) where do we configure that our app/service is soap 1.1 compatible or soap 1.2 compatible.

I'm using netbeans 7.3.1 with jdk 7.25 and glassfish 4.0.

Comment: Solution: you can bind your implementation class to SOAP 1.2 using : @BindingType(value="java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"). To confirm the binding your wsdl will have <SOAP12> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: you can bind your implementation class to SOAP 1.2 using :

```
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

You can confirm soap 1.2 binding by looking at your wsdl which will have tags like